# Link a PDF File to Output of EBS Concurrent Program

Tags: java, oracle, pdf, erp, oracle-ebs

We have created a Java Concurrent program which merges multiple PDF files into one. This new PDF created, sits on the Unix server and has a definite path.

I need to link this PDF file to the output of Oracle EBS Concurrent Program, i.e. when user clicks 'View Output', this PDF file should open up.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks,
Shubham

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be generic since you did not submit any code to your question.

Took for granted that your architecture is a client-server model.

Lets suppose that you have a link (View Output) where on the user clicks in order to download the specific PDF file. Since you are using an MVC architecture then, when the user clicks on the aforementioned link a method of `YourController` class will be invoked. Lets say that this method is named `getPDF()`. Subsequently this method will call the `download()` method of the supposed `DownloaderService` service. Finally this service will use a Download utility which will proceed to the necessary actions in order the file to be retrieved from the server.

On the below link you could find some ideas of how you could implement this feature suggested by Oracle.

[Reading from URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)

In case you enrich your question with more details(code snippets) the answer will be updated accordingly.